# Unable to select custom item renderer (flex)

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Hi I have made the following item renderer in mxml, but when I use it in a list for some reason I can not select it. 
Am I doing something wrong?

```
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import com.pbsmedia.kanpeki.domain.calEvent.CalEventType;
[Bindable]
private var calEventType:CalEventType;
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
if(value != null)
{
calEventType = value as CalEventType;
colorBar.setStyle("backgroundColor", calEventType.eventColor);
}
}
]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Image source="{calEventType.icon}" />
<mx:Label text="{calEventType.name}" selectable="true"/>
<mx:HBox height="100%" width="100%" horizontalAlign="right" paddingRight="20">
<mx:Box id="colorBar" width="50" height="100%" >
</mx:Box>
```

The renderer is set up on creation complete of the list's parent component as
follows.

```
private function cc():void{
if(_itemRenderer != null)
{
lt.itemRenderer = getItemRendererFactory();
}
}
private function getItemRendererFactory():ClassFactory
{
return new ClassFactory(_itemRenderer);
}
```

I can't see any reason why I can't select it, any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted this. I was forgetting to call super.data = value in the override.

Comment: I need to paste a post-it with this on my monitor. It gets me every time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending a `HBox` for your custom renderer, try extending `ListItemRenderer` directly or a `Canvas`.

By the way, I'll assume you've pasted it wrong on the question, since you're starting with a

```
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
```

.. and closing with:

```
</mx:Box>
```